# useEffect infinite loop when trying to check if user is logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, auth0, use-effect, mobx

Im using auth0, and on when the app gets re rendered maybe on a page refresh, im trying to do a couple of things with auth0, 1st is check if the user is authenticated, and if he is save his token and user object in the mobx store else redirect him to the login page.
this is the code im currently using:

```
// appLoaded --> to check if the user is logged in (app cannot be used without a user)

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    // isAuthenticated,
    user,
    getIdTokenClaims,
    loginWithRedirect,
    isAuthenticated
  } = useAuth0();

  const {
    sideNavStore: { isOpen, toggleSideBar },
    authStore: { setAppLoaded, setToken, setUser, appLoaded }
  } = useStore();

  // get the user from auth0 and store their details in the mobx store;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getIdTokenClaims().then((response) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
        setToken(response.__raw);
        setUser(user);
      });
    } else {
      loginWithRedirect().then(() => {
        setAppLoaded(false);
      });
    }
  }, [
    isAuthenticated,
    setToken,
    setUser,
    setAppLoaded,
    loginWithRedirect,
    getIdTokenClaims,
    user
  ]);

  if (!appLoaded) return <PreLoader />;
return (
// some component code
)}
```

i run into an infinite loop in the code above. i have been on this issue for a day now and just decided to ask on here. could anyone please tell me what im doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update any state that a `useEffect` depends on from within it. That creates an infinite loop.

You have too many dependencies for single `useEffect` and you're updating some of them. Split your code into multiple `useEffect` with smaller number of dependencies, ensuring that each of them aren't updating it's own dependency

Comment: thanks, but how do i split that useeffect? its just doing a simple if else to check  if a user is logged in, the user is gotten from auth0 and sets it to the mobx app user(setUser), there is not state being modified and depended on there to my knowledge

Comment: Why are you running it when `setToken,
    setUser,
    setAppLoaded,` etc changes? And then you're setting those from the effect, creating a loop. You prob just need one dependency like `[ isAuthenticated]`

Comment: i still get the infinite loop when using only isAuthenticated as a dep

Comment: Probably because your code inside effect it is updating `isAuthenticated`. And you shouldn't do that. You need to architect your state in such a way.

Comment: @DBankx I can see that `isAuthenticated ` is coming from `useAuth0`. Things like `setToken`, `setUser` might be updating it behind the scenes. I recommend creating your own state that you have control over to decide when to run your hooks

Comment: thanks for the explaination, but the isAuthenticated just returns a boolean value, the set token and set user, i created using mobx and basically they set the values of the token gotten from the getIdTokenClaims and sets the user object from auth0 to mobx. maybe im misinterpreting your answer but im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231843/discussion-between-dbankx-and-t-j).

Comment: Does the loop go away if you remove all dependencies?